# Rails 4.1.4 ActionView::Base Default Form Builder Doesn't Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, actionview, ruby-on-rails-4.1, actionviewhelper

**Using Ruby 2.1.1 Rails 4.1.4**

Hi,

I've been banging my head on a really strange issue I'm seeing with FormHelper. I'm simply trying to build a form using `form_for` and I'm getting the `cannot call new for nil class` error when the view tries to render. Through the backtrace, I found that the issue is actually in:

`ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper#instantiate_builder:1145-1146`

```
builder = options[:builder] || default_form_builder
builder.new(object_name, object, self, options)
```

`default_form_builder` is defined as follows in `ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper`

```
def default_form_builder
   builder = ActionView::Base.default_form_builder
   builder.respond_to?(:constantize) ? builder.constantize : builder
 end
```

I have not added a Custom Form Builder and am simply trying to use the default. When I check what `ActionView::Base.default_form_builder` is, I get nil.

The 2 solutions to get it to work for me were:

1. Pass a Form Builder Object to the form_for options[:builder] hash
2. Add the following line in my environment config
   `config.action_view.default_form_builder = ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`

I'm using 2) for now but both of these shouldn't be necessary.

I've looked everywhere but no luck with what is going on. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have `gem 'extlib'` and `gem 'devise'` in Gemfile?
Move `gem 'extlib'` line under `gem 'devise'` line.

I don't know why but it will work...